# Unable to get Scoped Service in aspnetcore 1 - RC1 to work

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My scoped service for some reason seems to be generating different instances of the same class when I try to access it in 2 middlewares within the same request.

Scenario: I am adding a scoped service as such:

```
public interface ISimplyRecorder
    {
        void AddInfo(string key, string value);
        Dictionary<string, string> GetAllInfo();   
    }


public class SimplyCoreRecorderService : ISimplyRecorder
    {
        private Dictionary<string,string> data;

        public SimplyCoreRecorderService()
        {
            data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public void AddInfo(string key,string value)
        {
            data.Add("",value);
        }

        public Dictionary<string,string> GetAllInfo()
        {
            return data;
        }

    }
```

and then the following in startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<ISimplyRecorder,SimplyRecorderService>();
```

now I am calling this service in the constructor of a sample Middleware. I am able to access the service with a new instance and add data into it and then I call await _next(context). However, when I am calling the service in my HomeController, MVC which follows the middleware above, I seem to be getting a new instance of the service even though it's the same request.

HomeController:

```
ISimplyRecorder _simply;
private IHostingEnvironment _env;

public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env,ISimplyRecorder simply)
{
    _simply = simply;
    _env = env;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    _simply.AddInfo("Home:Action","resulted in index action");
    return View();
}
```

complete code available at: https://github.com/muqeet-khan/SimplyCore if someone wants to give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middlewares are instantiated only once when it's first involved, then all the following requests are handled by that middleware instance. NOT a new middleware instance for each request.

You get your `ISimplyRecorder` in the constructor of the middleware and "cache" it as a private readonly variable. This means the middleware will get the `ISimplyRecorder` instance of the first request, then keep adding data to that instance for all the following requests rather than the new `ISimplyRecorder` instance for the following requests which you get in `HomeController`.

To solve it, you need to get `ISimplyRecorder` instance from the `Invoke` method of the middleware.

```
// using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    ISimplyRecorder recoder = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISimplyRecorder>();
}
```

**EDIT:**

The comment of Juergen is correct, I tried it out. You may also just write like this:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISimplyRecorder recorder)
{
    // recorder is from DI
}
```

Comment: If I remember right, it should be possible to inject into the Invoke method like this:
`public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISimplyRecorder recoder )`

Comment: I will try it out soon but wasn't the default DI limited to constructor injection?

Comment: @Ma_Khan not really. For example the `Configure` method in `StartUp` class, the `Invoke` method of middleware and using `[FromService]` attribute for parameters in action methods of `Controller` (HomeController)

Comment: Tested and Success... Thank You!